# Apache Commons - ConfigurationInterpolator blocking threads

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-commons-config

In a multithreaded application I use the great Apache Commons library.
However, for some reason, half of my threads gets blocked when calling its *getList* and similar methods.

This is a sample of the threadump:

```
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.interpol.ConfigurationInterpolator. (ConfigurationInterpolator.java:138)
- locked <0x00000000855e6138> (a java.util.HashMap)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.createInterpolator(AbstractConfiguration.java:328)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getSubstitutor(AbstractConfiguration.java:292)
- locked <0x00000000d7293058> (a org.apache.commons.configuration.SubsetConfiguration)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertyConverter.interpolate(PropertyConverter.java:958)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.interpolate(AbstractConfiguration.java:446)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.SubsetConfiguration.interpolate(SubsetConfiguration.java:213)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.SubsetConfiguration.interpolate(SubsetConfiguration.java:218)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.interpolate(AbstractConfiguration.java:433)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.SubsetConfiguration.interpolate(SubsetConfiguration.java:224)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getString(AbstractConfiguration.java:1039)
at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getString(AbstractConfiguration.java:1018)
```

Every time a thread is blocked (by the *getList* or *getInt* or similar methods) the lock is in the ConfigurationInterplator class.
By looking at its source, I understand that the instantiation of the class is synchronized - however I only need to be able to read the properties, and do not need interpolation every time.

Is there a build in way in Apache Commons to get over this limitation? For example do not take the interpolation step every time and cache it somehow?

Thanks,
krisy

Answer (score 0):

After much research, this is what I've found:

http://www.mail-archive.com/commons-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg11231.html

> I confirm you cannot disable this interpolation

And the workaround

> by subclassing PropertiesConfiguration and overwriting the protected method interpolate(String) to return immediately the string specified